# What is the difference between API permissions and expose API in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, authorization, swagger

Hi I am working on Azure AD. I have one webapi project and swagger configured along with it. I have resisted two apps in azure ad. One for swagger and one for webapi app.   Now I want to implement authorization based on groups. So now I want to call groups from microsoft graph api. From here on wards I am confused.  To access groups I need to give permission to read graph in my azure Ad swagger app or webapi app? [image: Swagger Authentication]

Below is my code.

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                {
                    Type = "oauth2",
                    Flow = "implicit",
                    AuthorizationUrl = swaggerUIOptions.AuthorizationUrl,
                    TokenUrl = swaggerUIOptions.TokenUrl,
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                      { "read_user_groups", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Group.Read.All" }
                    }
                });
```

Now In azure Ad I have API Permissions and Expose API.

In my swagger App inside App registration I have API Permission and I have added Microsoft Graph and selected Groups.Read All. Then I have Expose API and we can add scopes. These two things are confusing me. My swagger app has to do groups based authorization on my web api? Can someone help me in this?

Comment: For "implement authorization based on groups", does it mean that you want to know which AD group the user is in cluded in when you call your web api?

Comment: Currently In jwt token I have hasgroups:true so I want to call graph api to get groups. So from which app i should call graph? from my webapi app or swagger app registred in azure ad

Comment: In fact, there is a way you can get the group claim (which can tell the user is in which groups) directly from jwt token. Is it what you want to implement?

Comment: But my intention is to call windows graph api.  So to call microsoft graph api I need token. To generate token I need client id. So which client id I should use? webapp or swagger?

Comment: Expose API means this app represents the API you need to access. API Permission means this app will be used to make requests to web API app or Microsoft Graph resources. So it depends on which app you are protecting. Do you want to use swagger app to access your API and Microsoft Graph at the same time?

Comment: I want to authorisation based on groups on my web api. To do this I should call Microsoft graph from web api right? I have swagger app also. I created .net core web api and added swagger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I think I have got your ideas.

You want to give an access (to your web API) to users according to a group they belong to. Is that correct?

So, you need to call Microsoft graph to see the user is in which group.

In this case, you should call Microsoft graph from web api application. (not swagger app)

**But**, it's unnecessary to be so complicated.

As I mentioned in the comment, you can directly get the groups the user is included in from your jwt token.

You can include Groups claim in your token as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes). You just need to modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest of your web api application:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

Then the token will contain the Ids of the groups that the use belongs to like below :

```
{
  "groups": ["1ce9c55a-9826-4e32-871c-a8488144bb32"]
}
```

Then you can implement your authorization logic based on the groups id of the user.

---

**Update:**

You could [add an appRole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#declare-app-roles-using-azure-portal) into your Azure AD app (your web api app) and [assign users and groups to roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles).

Then the users in the group will have the claim like below:

```
{
  "roles": ["{the role you customized}"]
}
```

After that, the role will be included in the access token. And you can implement your authorization logic based on the roles of the user.

Comment: Yes this is correct but after "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup" still I am getting hasgroups:true rather than group ids

Comment: @Niranjan I just tested it and it works fine for me. Make sure that you modify the manifest of web api application (not swagger app). If it still doesn't work. Please decode your access token in https://jwt.io/ and provide a screenshot of its claims.

Comment: I saw in jwt.io since I am using implicit flow I am getting hasgroups true as per this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens

Comment: @Niranjan For implicit flow, if the user is in 6 or more groups, the groups claim will become hasgroups: true. In this case, there is another way to get what you want. See my update in answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have created question with all details from start to end what I tried so far and what difficulties I am facing I have created fresh question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59714282/net-core-app-unable-to-get-user-details-from-microsoft-graph-api. Really appreciate If you can look into this and provide some feed back