# .Net core App unable to get user details from Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, authorization

Net core Web API project. I registered app in azure AD for Web API app. I configured swagger and I registered one more app in Azure AD.
I am trying to do authorization on my webapis based on groups. In appsettings.json I have all the values.

Below is my startup looks like.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services
               .AddAuthentication(o =>
               {
                   o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

               })
               .AddJwtBearer(o =>
               {
                   o.Authority = azureActiveDirectoryOptions.Authority;

                   o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {

                       ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                       {
                          azureActiveDirectoryOptions.AppIdUri,
                          azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId
                       },
                       ValidateIssuer = true
                   };
               });
            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, GroupsCheckHandler>();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {   
                options.AddPolicy("GroupsCheck", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupsCheckRequirement("2a39995a-8fd1-410e-99e2-11cf6046090d"));
                });
            });
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {

                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                {
                    Type = "oauth2",
                    Flow = "implicit",
                    AuthorizationUrl = swaggerUIOptions.AuthorizationUrl,
                    TokenUrl = swaggerUIOptions.TokenUrl
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                        { "oauth2", new[] { "readAccess", "writeAccess" } }
                });
            });
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {

                c.OAuthClientId(swaggerUIOptions.ClientId);
                c.OAuthClientSecret(swaggerUIOptions.ClientSecret);
                c.OAuthRealm(azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId);
                c.OAuthAppName("Swagger");
                c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new { resource = azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId });
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

When I run the application using https://localhost:44319/swagger
 [image: Swagger]

Now I have Authorize button in my swagger. Whenever I try to Authorize, It will ask me to enter user name and password. Authentication works as expected. Next I want to hit /api/values/users/{id}. the controller looks below.

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "GroupsCheck")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {

    }
```

I need group based authorization. In startup I have added policy.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {   
                options.AddPolicy("GroupsCheck", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupsCheckRequirement("2a39995a-8fd1-410e-99e2-11cf6046090d"));
                });
            });
```

Below is my GroupsCheckHandler.cs

```
 protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                  GroupsCheckRequirement requirement)
        {

                GraphServiceClient client = await MicrosoftGraphClient.GetGraphServiceClient();
                //Tried to get user and dint work for me
                var user = await client.Me.Request().GetAsync(); 
                //Here exception occurs
                var groupList = await client.Groups.Request().GetAsync();


                var result = false;
                foreach (var group in groupList)
                {
                    if (requirement.groups.Equals(group.Id))
                    {
                        result = true;
                    }
                }

                if (result)
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
        }
```

Below is my MicrosoftGraphClient.cs

```
public static async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphServiceClient()
        {
            // Get Access Token and Microsoft Graph Client using access token and microsoft graph v1.0 endpoint
            var delegateAuthProvider = await GetAuthProvider();
            // Initializing the GraphServiceClient
            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(graphAPIEndpoint, delegateAuthProvider);

            return graphClient;
        }


        private static async Task<IAuthenticationProvider> GetAuthProvider()
        {
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

            // ADAL includes an in memory cache, so this call will only send a message to the server if the cached token is expired.
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResource, clientCred).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token.ToString());
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });

            return delegateAuthProvider;
        }
```

Now Whenever I start hitting to my api am getting exception in groupshandler.cs

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

I have added Microsoft graph permission to my app in azure AD. I thing to read groups we need Admin consent. Here I am struggling. Below permission I can see under enterprise application in azure ad under user consent tab.

[image: Enterprise Apps in Azure AD]

Below is token format generated through authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync method

[image: JWT token]
Other side this token also looks strange to me and this is missing many fields.

Now someone please help me what wrong steps I have done in the above implementation. Can someone help in this regard. Any help would be very helpful for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using [client credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) to get the access Token. So you need to add application permissions(not delegated permissions) on Azure portal.

[image]

After adding the application permissions, you also need to grant admin consent.

Comment: Thanks. My application needs access to graph api so I need to give application permission and give admin consent right? Also my token looks different than normal token and missing few fields. May I know what would be the cause to this

Comment: @Niranjan  Yes, you are right. And if you have application permissions added, they will be returned in the access token.

Comment: Okay thanks In the above code whenever I try to get access token using authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync do I need to pass scopes also in the request?

Comment: @Niranjan You are using adal. Scope parameter is not needed.

Comment: So I am using v1. Scopes required only with v2 right?

Comment: @Niranjan Correct.